# Python loop code with try: & except: pass

Tags: python-3.x, loops

When scraping list of json files, sometimes, file are missing and can't be downloaded.
On my python script, when that case occurs, the script display an error

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError : Expecting value: linke 1 column 1 (char 0)

How can I ask to the script to continue the loop if error ?
I tried to put and try: except, but without success (IndentationError)

This is the code :

```
RACE_L = x1["pageProps"]["initialState"]["racecards"]["races"][today2]
for r1 in RACE_L:
    id_race = r1["uuid"]
    link2go = link_append + id_race + '.json'
    n1 = "races"
    n12 = "races"
    n2 = r1["uuid"]
    name1 = n12 + '-' + n2
    name1 = today2 + '_' + name1 + '.json'
    with open(path +'%s' %name1,'w',encoding='utf-8') as f2:
        print('Writing %s into file' %name1)
        r3 = requests.get(link2go, headers=headers)
        sleep(2)
        x3 = r3.json()
        json.dump(x3, f2, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: where's the code where you tried to put try and except block?

Comment: just below for r1 in RACE_L:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the try and except blocks this way-

```
RACE_L = x1["pageProps"]["initialState"]["racecards"]["races"][today2]
for r1 in RACE_L:
    try:
        id_race = r1["uuid"]
        link2go = link_append + id_race + '.json'
        n1 = "races"
        n12 = "races"
        n2 = r1["uuid"]
        name1 = n12 + '-' + n2
        name1 = today2 + '_' + name1 + '.json'
        with open(path +'%s' %name1,'w',encoding='utf-8') as f2:
            print('Writing %s into file' %name1)
            r3 = requests.get(link2go, headers=headers)
            sleep(2)
            x3 = r3.json()
            json.dump(x3, f2, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
    except:
        pass
```